# Связь модели и представления в yii

Tags: yii

Нужно из форм записать данные ввода в БД. В модели насколько я понимаю будет класс от CActiveRecord. Я не понимаю, как в модели получить данные из представления? В контроллере понятно. Но везде написано, что закладывать логику в контроллер - это неправильно. Как быть?

П.С. В yii полный новичок и скорее всего чего-то не понимаю. Ух, надеюсь этот фреймворк стоит таких мучений))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы, вероятно, слабо представляете общие принципы MVC.

Управляет всем контроллер. Он получает внешние параметры (GET/POST), зная эти параметры он обращается к модели чтобы получить данные, и, затем, данные полученные из модели передаются представлению.

То-есть, представление генерится в самую последнюю очередь на основе данных модели, и вопрос "как в модели получить данные из представления?" теряет смысл.

Comment: Может и так((